# Challenges with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, user-input

This is what I have to do:
Display the numbers of students in each of the Levels `(R, 1, 2, 3, 4).`

```
Level R (mark < 50)     
Level 1 ( (mark >= 50) && (mark < 60) )    
Level 2 ( (mark >= 60) && (mark < 70) )     
Level 3 ( (mark >= 70) && (mark < 80) )    
Level 4 (mark >= 80).
```

This is what I have:

```
int L0=0,L1=0,L2=0,L3=0,L4=0;
    int acceptmarks=0;
        acceptmarks=Integer.parseInt(marksinput.getText());
    for(int i=0; i < marks.size(); i++){
    if (acceptmarks<50){
        L0=L0+1;}
    else if ((acceptmarks>=50) && (acceptmarks<60)){
        L1=L1+1;}
    else if ((acceptmarks>=60) && (acceptmarks<70)){
        L2=L2+1;}
    else if ((acceptmarks>=70) && (acceptmarks < 80)){
        L3=L3+1;}
    else if ((acceptmarks>=80) && (acceptmarks < 100)){
        L4=L4+1;}}
    int[] level= new int [5];
    level[0]=L0;
    level[1]=L1;
    level[2]=L2;
    level[3]=L3;
    level[4]=L4;
        analyzeoutput.setText("Numbers at Level 4:" + level[4]+ "\nNumbers at Level 3:" + 
            level[3]+ "\nNumbers at Level 2:" + level[2]+ "\nNumbers at Level 1:" + level[1]+ "\nNumbers at Level R:" + level[0]);
```

The problem I'm having is it does not displays the correct number of students for each level.

This is what happens:
Ex. I input 4 marks: `45, 66, 84, 89.`
Correct answer should be **1 mark in Level R, 1 in Level 2 and 2 in Level 4.**   But my program just counts the last mark. Since, last mark is 89(level 4), it displays all marks has level 4. I have spent hours on this.
Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED and thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** I figured it out. I just needed to replace acceptmarks with marks.get(i) in the if statements.

Comment: what is the value for marksinput.getText();

Comment: I guess acceptmarks  should be replaced with marks[i]

Comment: i will try that and marksinput is for the user to input the numbers/marks

Comment: too many unknowns here. what is marks, what is marksinput, how is this code called?

Comment: `marks` is your number of levels, `acceptmarks` is your input mark to check (it's `mark` in requirement above), right?

Comment: This obviously isnt the whole program as many of it would irrelevant, so I did not post it but I figured it out thanks to @Jobin Thank you so much Really appreciate your help

Comment: Just a hint, you are using if-else, so in the first else, you know that the value is not `< 50`, so you can remove `>= 50` in the condition ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int L0=0,L1=0,L2=0,L3=0,L4=0;
    List<Integer> marks = Arrays.asList(45, 66, 84, 89);
    for(int i = 0; i < marks.size(); i++){
        if (marks.get(i)<50){
            L0=L0+1;}
        else if ((marks.get(i)>=50) && (marks.get(i)<60)){
            L1=L1+1;}
        else if ((marks.get(i)>=60) && (marks.get(i)<70)){
            L2=L2+1;}
        else if ((marks.get(i)>=70) && (marks.get(i) < 80)){
            L3=L3+1;}
        else if ((marks.get(i)>=80) && (marks.get(i)< 100)){
            L4=L4+1;}}
    int[] level= new int [5];
    level[0]=L0;
    level[1]=L1;
    level[2]=L2;
    level[3]=L3;
    level[4]=L4;


    final JLabel analyzeoutput = new JLabel();
    analyzeoutput.setText("Numbers at Level 4:" + level[4]+ "\nNumbers at Level 3:" +
            level[3]+ "\nNumbers at Level 2:" + level[2]+ "\nNumbers at Level 1:" + level[1]+ "\nNumbers at Level R:" + level[0]);
    }
```

Note: If you can put all input that you are getting in "acceptmarks" to marks array. this will work.

AcceptMarks is an integer so it will contain only last input that you have given. either make AcceptMarks as a list or use marks as the array as shown in code snippet. I am using marks because you are looping on marks.

Comment: Please, don't post code with explaning what you have done and why.

Comment: Why Do you think I havn't ? I have written it in notes before giving votes please check answer properly.

Comment: You do know that this is written when you have edited your answer, and that we can see exactly what was edited ? And the one line that was there before doesn't explain AT ALL what you have done.

Comment: I know I have edited for more detail but I previously  thought one line was quite self-explanatory but anyways thanks.

Comment: By the way, you might access 9times to the same item of the list... you could simply use a `int marks = marks.get(i):` ... this is really bad

Answer (score 1):

you should move this statement

```
acceptmarks=Integer.parseInt(marksinput.getText());
```

inside the for loop

```
for(int i=0; i < marks.size(); i++){
```

and dont forget that

```
L0=L0+1;
```

is cutter when written as

```
l0++; //camelCase for the name and using advantages of the language
```

Comment: I would add that you could work with the level[] directly, instead of using l0, l1, l2, l3, ... ;) And don't forget to accept an answer if it helps you.